# How can I get a list of all Amazon Instant movies?

Tags: amazon

In Germany we can finally see movies online with Amazon Instant Video but they can only be sorted by Amazon user rating which is quite useless especially when the number of votes is low. IMDB and other review sites give better scores so I would like to create a search interface which orders Amazon movies by IMDB score. For this to work I need a list of all Amazon movies along with their title, URL and at best also more like the year and description (is there an international identification number for movies?). Is there any way to get this information?

P.S. Is it legally allowed to publish this data?